# Gocardless implementation in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, gocardless

I'm setting up a payment gateway using Gocardless API. I've tried to download and set it up manually, since I don't have composer.

This is a piece of code that I got from the documentation:

```php
require_once APPPATH.'third_party/gocardless/lib/loader.php';
$access_token = "sandbox_xyz";
$client = new \GoCardlessPro\Client(array(
  'access_token' => $access_token,
  'environment'  => \GoCardlessPro\Environment::SANDBOX
));

$client->customers()->list();

$client->customers()->list([
  "params" => ["created_at[gt]" => "2015-11-03T09:30:00Z"]
]);
```

I expect a list of customers to be added in Gocardless, but I'm getting this  error:

```
An uncaught Exception was encountered
Type: Error

Message: Class 'GuzzleHttp\HandlerStack' not found

Filename: /var/www/html/myapp/application/third_party/gocardless/lib/Client.php

Line Number: 43
```

I assume that I am doing something incorrectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation under [manual installation](https://github.com/gocardless/gocardless-pro-php#manual-installation), you also need to `require` [Guzzle's](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/releases/tag/6.3.3) **autoloader.php** in the **guzzle.zip** in the **src** directory.